# Custom ExoPlayer MediaSource -- where to start?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm working on creating a custom media player using ExoPlayer (I've previously opened several questions on the same topic, because I'm very new to Android development and it seems like I run into a wall with every line of code I write).

As part of this custom player I would like to download, parse, and handle an XML file that our business produces to define our content. This XML file gives a URL for a network ID (a 4-6 second video advertising the owner of the content), a URL for the content, and an ad tag URL for playing pre-roll and mid-roll ads.

My goal is to pass this XML file as a video source to `prepare()`, call `setPlayWhenReady(true)`, then have everything play as expected (network ID, content, and ads)

To do this I believe I need to create a custom MediaSource -- however I cannot find any good documentation or tutorials on doing so. [The ExoPlayer documentation on MediaSources](https://exoplayer.dev/media-sources.html) is practically useless on this case, only describing how to utilize ConcatenatingMediaSource, MergingMediaSource, and LoopingMediaSource to customize the playback of media.

### Update

Continuing to research on my own, it's possible what I want may be accomplished with a custom Extractor. When I pass the content to an ExtractorMediaSource I receive the error `com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (MatroskaExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor, AmrExtractor) could read the stream.`. This makes me wonder if it's better to have an **Extractor** parse the XML, pull the content, and pass the data back. I'm not sure yet what the difference is between these two components or which is a better fit, and the documentation is lacking.

Comment: "My goal is to pass this XML file as a video source to prepare(), call setPlayWhenReady(true), then have everything play as expected (network ID, content, and ads)" -- why do you think that this is the responsibility of a `View`? IMHO, downloading and parsing the XML should be the responsibility of a repository, or at worst a viewmodel.

Comment: We plan on distributing our player as a library for clients to use in their own apps. The same way you can currently instantiate a `MediaPlayer`, throw a video at it, and it just plays like magic -- I want people to be able to instantiate a `BFPlayer`, throw a video at it, and it just plays like magic... with the added benefit that it will know how to play our content. Therefore the parsing of this XML file should be the responsibility of the video player, not of the client's app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Therefore the parsing of this XML file should be the responsibility of the video player, not of the client's app.

So you are essentially trying to create a new schema for distributing video for an underlying player (whatever that might be, to deal with). This seems like client side logic. However, you want an answer so I'll try and give you one.

First, `Extractor` in `ExoPlayer` should not be used for parsing your `XML`, as per the docs:

> Extracts media data from a container format.

This would be used for extracting the video data from a video container e.g. MP4.

In your scenario you probably want to look at something similar to the `DashManifestParser` who uses the `ParsingLoadable.Parser` whose responsibility it is to parse your input model. This `ParsingLoadable.Parser` is then used by `MediaSource` to get the information it needs for playback.

However, I would not recommend doing any of that. The best option for you in this scenario would be to create a `Parser` to grab the content Url and just pass that to an underlying player. You content Url will link to an `MP4` container, perhaps DRM'd content etc, but all of that can be handled by the player just fine without adding all of this other complexity.

As for creating adverts, this can be done in a number of ways:

- Have a single player instance, swapping between content and adverts. Easy but then you need to keep track of position information and also you will have buffering when you switch.
- Have a single player instance but use `ConcatenatingMediaSource`, for this you would parse the `xml` create a `MediaSource` for the content and each advert, you then add these to the `ConcatenatingMediaSource`.
- Have a single player instance but use the `AdsLoader` provided by `ExoPlayer`. This is the best solution but the documentation is sadly lacking. For this you can provide a link to load adverts and a separate link to load content.

So. To summarise.

- Create a parser that can get the info you need from the XML i.e. content link and advert links.
- Create a player that creates a media source for the content and then media sources for the adverts, add these to the concatenating media source.

If you'd like to see how to do certain aspects I would suggest taking a look at our open source library that uses `Exo-Player` under the hood. We've even recently started to use an `AdsLoader`. https://github.com/novoda/no-player

Comment: This has definitely got me pointed in a good direction. One quick question regarding ads -- all of your solutions (switching the content, a `ConcatenatingMediaSource`, and an `AdsLoader`) sound like they don't allow ads and content to be parsed simultaneously. This sounds like it would prevent me from receiving metadata events from the content during an adbreak. Is there a way to leave the content "playing" in the background, but muted and not displaying anything, so that I can continue to receive metadata events?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean by `don't allow ads and content to be parsed simultaneously`. If you mean that you need to load them separately in the player, then yes, you are correct. ConcatenatingMediaSource would require you to swap tracks if you want to handle adverts. You can use an `AdsLoader` to load "simultaneously", but it's not exactly simultaneous, the assets are only loaded when the player gets to a certain point in the buffer, something like 10-20 seconds before the advert starts.

Comment: "Is there a way to leave the content "playing" in the background, but muted and not displaying anything, so that I can continue to receive metadata" You mean stopping the player? I don't really follow the point of the metadata events and how these come from the content.

Comment: our content is HLS-encoded and consists of three streams: a video stream, an audio stream, and a timed metadata stream (ID3). The timed metadata stream is used to time ads with the content (instead of playing an ad randomly 5 minutes after you start watching, we can wait until there's a lull in the action to throw an ad). We plan to extract metadata from the content using https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference-v1/com/google/android/exoplayer/metadata/MetadataTrackRenderer.MetadataRenderer.html

Comment: It sounds strange to me to receive metadata events associated with content when playing adverts. It make more sense to `pause` the content and play the adverts and then resume the content when the adverts are complete.

Comment: The content is live sports content, not movies or TV shows. During the live event when there's a break in the game, rain delay, half-time, etc the person manning the camera can press a button to say "trigger an ad break", and it injects metadata into the content telling us to throw an ad. If the game resumes early or if something stream-worthy happens during the break, they can press another button to say "end the ad break early", and it injects metadata into the content telling us to clean up any playing ad and go back to content immediately. It makes sense because it's live